# Spring 4 with Java Config and no xml

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I'm working on a Spring 4 based Java application.  This application is being deployed to Apache Tomcat.  This application runs at a URL of http://localhost:8080/test.  I can't get the GET method defined in the controller class to run.  I'm pretty sure it's a configure issue.  See what I am doing wrong?  This does work when I run the app at the root URL of http://localhost:8080/, but this is not an option for me.  First Class involved:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class TestWebInitializer extends      
   AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/test" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }
}
```

2nd class involved:

```
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/test"})
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(method=GET)
    public String home() {
        //TODO: Convert System.out.println to log4j     
        System.out.println("HomeController.home()!");

        return "home";
    }
}
```

Comment: "method = Get" did it compile properly?

Comment: What handler method should handle the URI  `http://localhost:8080/`?

Comment: Which URL are you calling to "get the GET method [...] to run"? In your current setup, `TestController#home()` will be at `http://localhost:8080/test/test`.

Comment: Or even /test/test/test, AFAIK, if the context path of the webapp is test (i.e. your war is test.war and not ROOT.war)

Answer (score 0):

@hzpz is correct, `getServletMappings()` controlls which paths **within** your application's context root gets handled by the servlet (instead of other servlets in the same WAR). Your config matched the bold part:

`http://localhost:8080/context_root/test`

To change the context root, you should change the name of the WAR (from ROOT.war) or change the config file of your application server.

The application server also strips any matched portion of the context root and servlet mapping pattern, so if your application is correctly deployed to be the app at `http://localhost:8080/test` (i.e. with a context root of `/test`), its servlets will only see a path after the `/test`, so your `@RequestMapping` should handle `"/"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat - go to server.xml inside tomcat and place below code there.

```
<Context 
  docBase="<yourApp>" 
  path="/" 
  reloadable="true" 
/>
```